# React Native Maps for Web IOS and Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

What is the best react native map for all platforms, that work together?

I am using expo
Tried using this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/

But when I do it breaks my whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used "react-native-maps" as well and it worked well with Expo, both on iOS and Android. As far as I know, it's your best option with Expo.

Here's how I had it setup (Feel free to ingnore the context bit - just wanted to show the drawing capabilities as well):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Polyline, Circle } from 'react-native-maps';
import {Context as LocationContext} from "../context/LocationContext";


const Map = () => {
    const { state: { currentLocation, locations }} = useContext(LocationContext);
    if(!currentLocation)
        return <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={styles.activityIndicator}/>;
    return <>
        <MapView 
            style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={{
                ...currentLocation.coords,
                latitudeDelta: 1,
                longitudeDelta:1,
            }}
        >
            <Circle 
                center= {currentLocation.coords}
                radius= {2000}
                color="rgba(158, 158, 255, 1.0)"
                fillColor="rgba(158, 158, 255, 0.3)"
            />
             <Polyline 
                coordinates={ locations.map((item) => item.coords )}
                lineDashPattern={[1, 0]}
            />
        </MapView>
    </>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map:{
        height: 300,
    },
    activityIndicator:{
        marginTop: 200
    }
});

export default Map;
```

Comment: Looks Good, But does it work with web?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you'd need to have a separate module for the Web indeed. Usually people tend to struggle with Expo and Maps. On the web side, things should be a bit more straight forward. I've used this one quite successfully in the past. If you need to sync RN and web maps, I'd do it server side. Does this help?

Comment: Does the drawing feature work? 
Because from what I read features like the Polyline, Circle, or custom markers don't seem to work on the Web?

Like I'm using Expo for IOS Android and Web, and Im looking for a Map that works on all of the platforms and has the same features. 

Also Looked into MapBox but  I dont think it works with Expo....